# Pass values to a button from function

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a function which is receiving parameters from another function and I have to pass these parameters to a button when it's execution get's complete !

```
 async void CallCompanyApi(String CompanyGp, string CompanyId)
        {
            First.IsVisible = false;
            Second.IsVisible = true;
         //   Next_Clicked(CompanyGp,CompanyId)                    
        }
  


private void Next_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I have to pass these 2 parameters to that button !

Comment: store them in a class level variable so you can reference them from anywhere in your class

Comment: Actually these values I am getting from api and storing in variables so I have to pass that way only after execution is completed !

Comment: Is their way to pass them to button !

Comment: you don't really pass values "to" a button.  Your description of the scenario is not very clear

Comment: These string values which I recieved I passed to a function on successful execution of function I have to pass values from this function to button !

Comment: that still doesn't make any sense.  What is the button going to do with these values?  Are you trying to set the button's text property?  Or is the button going to use these values for some purpose when it is clicked?

Comment: This button will then pass these values to another page and they will be used there !

Comment: are CompanyGp and CompanyId the values you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create **class level** variables to store these values

```
string _CompanyGp;
string _CompanyId;

async void CallCompanyApi(String CompanyGp, string CompanyId)
{
    First.IsVisible = false;
    Second.IsVisible = true;

    // store the parameters in the class level variables
    _CompanyGp = CompanyGp;
    _CompanyId = CompanyId;
}
  
private void Next_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // you can now just reference _CompanyGp and _CompanyId
}
```

FYI, this is basic C# and really has nothing specific to do with Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

If `CallCompanyApi` and `Next_Clicked` located in different class, you can store them in Xamarin Forms by **[using Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#using-preferences)**.

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

async void CallCompanyApi(String CompanyGp, string CompanyId)
{
     First.IsVisible = false;
     Second.IsVisible = true;
     //Next_Clicked(CompanyGp,CompanyId)
     Preferences.Set("CompanyGp", CompanyGp);
     Preferences.Set("CompanyId", CompanyId);                     
}
```

Then in another class, click button will get them:

```
private void Next_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var CompanyGp = Preferences.Get("CompanyGp", "default_value");
    var CompanyId = Preferences.Get("CompanyId", "default_value");
}
```

Else if they are in the same class, you can use the way as Jason's said.

============================Update=========================

You can set a default value if needed, such as follow:

```
var CompanyGp = Preferences.Get("CompanyGp", "Company_A");
var CompanyId = Preferences.Get("CompanyId", "1");
```

Defalut `CompanyGp` is *Company_A*, and default `CompanyId` is *1*.

Comment: What is the default value here refers too !

Comment: @NavuKinger The default value can be setted by yourself if needed. The scene used for not storing value, also can get a default value from `Preferences`.

Comment: In case I don't want to set any default value can I remove it from there ?

Comment: @NavuKinger Yes, you can. Just set `""` . Such as this: `var CompanyGp = Preferences.Get("CompanyGp", "");`

Comment: @NavuKinger If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.